# My 32-bit Video For Windows based app doesn't work under Win7/64 or Vista/64?

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-vista, vista64, vfw

I wrote a program that relies on Video For Windows. It worked fine under XP & Vista 32-bit OSes, but now I am trying to run it on the newer 64-bit OSes it isn't able to open any AVI files. The actual program starts up fine, the GUI appears, the File Open dialog works fine, but the VFW library is saying it cannot open some generic AVI files that use several different codecs.

Anybody know if VFW support has been dropped from the 64-bit OSes, or could it be something else?

Thanks.

Comment: My bet is that your application is installing (and relying upon) the 32-bit versions of the appropriate codecs for playing AVI files. You need the 64-bit versions on a 64-bit version of Windows.

Comment: AVI is a container format.  The actual video streams inside of it require the appropriate codec to be installed.  Which you obviously don't have available in a 64-bit version or on this (new?) install of Windows.

Answer (score 3):

> Anybody know if VFW support has been dropped from the 64-bit OSes?

VFW works in 64 bit Windows just the same as it ever did on 32 bit Windows.

You probably don't have the codecs installed but that's just a guess because you didn't give any details of error messages.

Answer (score 1):

VfW works in x64 machines, but only if your process is x86. An x64 process will only be able to open x64 codecs. x64 codecs do exist, but they are rare, and need to be installed.

If your process has to be x64, and you have to access x86 codecs, then the only way to do it is to have a multiprocess architecture, with a child process doing the file read and passing the data to the x64 parent via named pipes.